# IF function: equals a sum does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a cell (A40) in an Excel worksheet which contains the sum of a range of values (formula: `=SUM(A1:A39)`).

Another cell should print "OK" if the sum is 0 and "ERROR" if the sum is not 0. I have the following formula: `=IF(A40=0;"OK";"ERROR")`. Unfortunately it always prints "ERROR".

A1 to A40 are all in the format "Currency" if that matters.

Is this another "never compare floating points to fixed values, instead use a small epsilon range"-error? The following fix works... `=IF(AND(A40>-0,1; A40<0,1);"OK";"ERROR")`. How many zeroes are "enough" to always get the correct "OK" or "ERROR" output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are going to have problems comparing a floating point to an integer. Try `=IF(ROUND(A40;2)=0;"OK";"ERROR")`

This will first round your sum to two decimal places, then do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you, `ROUND` is a much better idea than to use a more complicated formula for an epsilon-range comparison!